# using Parameters in Crystal Report, work fine but dynamic record does not print when printing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Hi
I am fetching data from database and using parameters for crystal report, i post parameters from asp.net textboxes and receive in crystal report, it works fine and reports generates perfectly, but when i print it, only that record prints which is non db based, and dynamic records do not print, please help....

Comment: i accept every correct answer, i dont know why it is like this.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem solved by myself, posting an answer for the help of people who would use SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010.

When you generate a crystal report from asp form, using parameters, the report is generated, and when you print, the page refreshes, which wastes the parameters of post, as it refreshes. So null parameters are passed to it, thats why database based rows will be empty, solution is use query string, or save the post variables in session and pick them on page load.

:)

Thanks